# adding color pallet to base R plot function

Tags: r, plot

Question: I have been attempting to use the pallet Wes_Anderson to give me 1 color for species... so the first line does that but since it is using the base R colors I have no control over them. I am using the base Iris data set on R.

`graph = plot(data$Petal.Width, data$Petal.Length, pch = 16, col =( data$Species))`

I have attempted to add them by using this..

`graph + scale_fill_manual (values = wes_palette("Zissou1", n = 3, type = "discrete"))`

The reason why I want to add them is because I am trying to specify what I am making for the legend coded below. I am trying to ensure the species match my wes_anderson pallet...
I don't understand why I can't specify the colors from the col = data$Species column while using the wes_anderson pallet

```
legend("topleft", inset = 0.05,
legend=paste(rep(c("setosa","versicolor","virginica"))),
       col = wes_palette("Zissou1", 3, type = c("discrete")),
       pch = 16,
       #this is for a box around the legend
       bty="black")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the palette as the species factor labels and then convert it to a character string.

```
library(wesanderson)

pal <-  wes_palette("Zissou1", length(levels(iris$Species)))

with(iris,
     plot(
       Petal.Width,
       Petal.Length,
       pch = 16,
       col = as.character(factor(Species, labels = pal))
     ))

legend("topleft", inset = 0.05,
       legend=levels(iris$Species),
       col =  pal,
       pch = 16,
       #this is for a box around the legend
       bty="black")
```

As an aside, it looks like you were trying to mix base plotting and functions from `ggplot2` which is not going to work.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Can you clarify which functions are ggplot2 specific? I thought something was off but I wasn't sure what.

Comment: I have a followup question. Would the legend as written translate to the colors that are being assigned to each species?

Comment: In this case yes, but only because the species vector provided in the legend function happened to be in alphabetical order.  I've made an edit to show how to control this safely.